# PowerMockito gives NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito, powermockito

I'm trying to set up a unit test with Mockito and PowerMockito, but it throws:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/mockito/exceptions/Reporter

whenever I try to run a test. These are my dependencies:

```
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.8.9'
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:1.6.5'
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.7.4'
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems you are trying to use incompatible versions.

According to this [table](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#supported-versions), you need to use version `1.7.x` of Powermock in order to be compatible with your Mockito version `2.8.9`.

Comment: Fixed using testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:1.7.3'

Answer (score 1):

Add these dependencies in your `external-dependencies.xml`-

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-support</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-reflect</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4-common</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

#### Explanation-

1. `powermock 1.5.6` has issue with `junit 4.12` - that requires `powermock
   1.6.1 :: org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.FieldNotFoundException`: Field 'fTestClass' was not found in class
2. `org.junit.internal.runners.MethodValidator powermock 1.6.1` requires more current *mockito* :: No methods matching the name(s) add were found in the class hierarchy
   of interface `org.mockito.internal.util.MockitoSpy`.
3. Switching to `powermock 1.6.2` with upgraded mockito to `1.10.8`:: results `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`:
   `org/mockito/internal/creation/util/MockitoMethodProxy`
                   switch to `mockito-core 1.10.19`     and   `org.powermock 1.6.4`