# Unable to use PowerMock with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, junit, powermock

All my tests are running fine with "mvn test" command. However when I'm using eclipse IDE to run tests, it no longer works. I got this exception error :

```
org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.FieldNotFoundException: No instance field named "reporter" could be found in the class hierarchy of org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.matcherstrategies.FieldNameMatcherStrategy.notFound(FieldNameMatcherStrategy.java:40)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.findSingleFieldUsingStrategy(WhiteboxImpl.java:501)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.findFieldInHierarchy(WhiteboxImpl.java:454)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.findFieldInHierarchy(WhiteboxImpl.java:442)
```

I already read some topics about that. It seems it is due to some junit/powermock versions compatibility :
[Unable to run JUnit test with PowerMockRunner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26192929/unable-to-run-junit-test-with-powermockrunner)

But I think my versions are correct :

```
<junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
<powermock.version>1.7.3</powermock.version>
```

Comment: A liitle late though.Please find the answer here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49130081/powermockito-gives-noclassdeffounderror

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is an incompatible version. Please, try to check the versions: [Versions](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#supported-versions)